# How to use java.util.Optional of a Set with jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I am having issues adapting an `Optional` that contains a `Set`.

Initially we had a Set within an class that was to be marshalled to XML as such:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
@XmlElement(name = "item")
public Set<Item> getItems()
{
    return items;
}
```

We create a schema from our classes during the maven build. However the requirement has changed, and the `Set` now has to be wrapped in an `Optional` but we still need the output schema to remain the same.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
@XmlElement(name = "item")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = OptionalAdapter.class)
public Optional<Set<Item>> getItem()
{
    return items;
}
```

After wrapping the Set as such I have created the xml adapter:

```
public class OptionalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Set<Item>,Optional<Set<Item>>>
{
    @Override
     public Optional<Set<Item>> unmarshal(final Set<Item> v) throws Exception
     {
        return Optional.ofNullable(v);
     }

     @Override
     public Set<Item> marshal(final Optional<Set<Item>> v) throws Exception
     {
         return v.orElse(null);
     }

 }
```

After changing the classes, `schemagen` fails (the maven output is just '`null`', as far as I'm aware this is a known issue with the `schemagen`).

I have tried changing the adapter to use collection and to remove the `XmlElementWrapper` annotation from the optional but have had no luck. I was wondering if there was anything else that needs to be taken care of in order for this to generate the schema (and marshal/unmarshal) correctly?

Many Thanks